# Testing tools for Sonic and IBM MQ

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq, sonicmq

I need to test the message flow in SONIC and also in IBM websphere MQ. Is there any tools to test the message flow for these?

Thanks,
i2ijeya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate your question?

But :

if you want to test an outbound connection to Websphere MQ you can use the internal test scenario (in Sonic Workbench) and set a process with the onRamp/OffRamp Websphere MQ service(but it's not out of the box and requires the Service configuration).
Otherwise to put a jms Message in a Sonic Queue you can use the internal JMSClient or SonicMessageManager ([http://queuemanager.nl/] it has more options and use the ESB lib not only the jms ones)

if you want to send messages and get messages from Websphere MQ the easiest way is to use :
   - IBM mq tool
   - MQJExplorer [https://code.google.com/p/mqjexplorer/]

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Hope this should help me out. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I have added a little more details because it was a bit unclear. Cheers